# Testing Navigation component: "does not have a NavController"

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel

I'm implementing Espresso tests. I'm using a Fragment with a `NavGraph` scoped `ViewModel`. The problem is when I try to test the `Fragment` I got an `IllegalStateException` because the `Fragment` does not have a `NavController` set. How can I fix this problem?

```
class MyFragment : Fragment(), Injectable {

    private val viewModel by navGraphViewModels<MyViewModel>(R.id.scoped_graph){
        viewModelFactory
   }

    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory
    //Other stuff
}
```

Test class:

```
class FragmentTest {

    class TestMyFragment: MyFragment(){
        val navMock = mock<NavController>()

        override fun getNavController(): NavController {
            return navMock
        }
    }

    @Mock
    private lateinit var viewModel: MyViewModel
    private lateinit var scenario: FragmentScenario<TestMyFragment>

    @Before
    fun prepareTest(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)

    scenario = launchFragmentInContainer<TestMyFragment>(themeResId = R.style.Theme_AppCompat){
        TestMyFragment().apply {
            viewModelFactory = ViewModelUtil.createFor(viewModel)
        }
    }

    // My test
}
```

Exception I got:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: View android.widget.ScrollView does not have a NavController setjava.lang.IllegalStateException
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As can be seen in [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-testing#test_navigationui_with_fragmentscenario), here's the suggested approach:

```
// Create a mock NavController
val mockNavController = mock(NavController::class.java)

scenario = launchFragmentInContainer<TestMyFragment>(themeResId = R.style.Theme_AppCompat) {
    TestMyFragment().also { fragment ->     
        // In addition to returning a new instance of our Fragment,
        // get a callback whenever the fragment’s view is created
        // or destroyed so that we can set the mock NavController
        fragment.viewLifecycleOwnerLiveData.observeForever { viewLifecycleOwner ->
            if (viewLifecycleOwner != null) {
                // The fragment’s view has just been created
                Navigation.setViewNavController(fragment.requireView(), mockNavController)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thereafter you can perform verification on mocked `mockNavController` as such:

```
verify(mockNavController).navigate(SearchFragmentDirections.showRepo("foo", "bar"))
```

See [architecture components sample](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/androidTest/java/com/android/example/github/ui/search/SearchFragmentTest.kt) for reference.

---

There exists another approach which is mentioned in [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-testing#test_fragment_navigation) as well:

```
    // Create a graphical FragmentScenario for the TitleScreen
    val titleScenario = launchFragmentInContainer<TitleScreen>()

    // Set the NavController property on the fragment
    titleScenario.onFragment { fragment ->
        Navigation.setViewNavController(fragment.requireView(), mockNavController)
    }
```

This approach won't work in case there happens an interaction with `NavController` up until `onViewCreated()` (included). Using this approach `onFragment()` would set mock `NavController` too late in the lifecycle, causing the `findNavController()` call to fail. As a unified approach which will work for all cases I'd suggest using first approach.

Comment: The Illegal exception has been fixed, but now I got a problem with the navMock, when the ViewModel is being created it tries to get the backstack, but as it is a Mock null is returned and the test fails. As it is a Mock I can´t stub the method that gets the NavBackStackEntry, and I can´t find an easy way to test a Fragment with `navGraphViewModels `

Comment: Seems like the issue you outline is related to other thing, which actually has no connection to this question. At this point I do not have enough information in order to understand what's the issue with your code. Feel free to outline detailed error log and code so that I can have a glance at it.

Comment: @azizbekian This approach works but only if you don't need to set a graph on your mocked navcontroller. I'm struggling with this issue, case here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60191801/navigation-components-mocking-navcontroller-graph

Comment: I get an error which say backstack is empty

Comment: you will need to set navController.setViewModelStore(ViewModelStore()) if you pass some data

Comment: Neither of these approaches work if findNavController() is called from onCreate(). How do we test navigation from onCreate()? (e.g. a conditional redirect)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing setting the `NavController`:

```
testFragmentScenario.onFragment {
            Navigation.setViewNavController(it.requireView(), mockNavController)
        }
```