# Navigation components - Mocking Navcontroller graph

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing, android-architecture-navigation

I'm using navigation components and I'm trying to test my `Fragment` with instrumented test. The fragment has a custom toolbar initialized in `onViewCreated` method by an extension function.

```kotlin
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    tbBlack.init()
}


fun androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar.init(
    menuId: Int? = null
) {
    title = ""
    menuId?.let {
        inflateMenu(it)
    }

    findNavController().let {
        it.graph.let { graph ->
            val configuration = AppBarConfiguration(graph)
            setupWithNavController(it, configuration)
        }
    }
}
```

During the initialization of the scenario in my instrumented test, the test crashes due to a `null` graph on the Nav Controller.

The nav controller is mocked in the test, as well as the graph like below:

```kotlin
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class LoginFragmentTest {
    @Test
    fun testEmptyFields() {
        val mockNavController = mock(NavController::class.java)
        val mockGraph = mock(NavGraph::class.java)
        mockNavController.graph = mockGraph

        val scenario = launchFragmentInContainer(themeResId = R.style.AppTheme) {
            LoginFragment().also { fragment ->
                // In addition to returning a new instance of our Fragment,
                // get a callback whenever the fragment’s view is created
                // or destroyed so that we can set the mock NavController
                fragment.viewLifecycleOwnerLiveData.observeForever { viewLifecycleOwner ->
                    if (viewLifecycleOwner != null) {
                        // The fragment’s view has just been created
                        Navigation.setViewNavController(fragment.requireView(), mockNavController)
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        scenario.onFragment {
            it.run {
                val viewsIds =
                    listOf(R.id.etEmailAddress, R.id.etPassword)

                for (viewId in viewsIds) {
                    onView(ViewMatchers.withId(viewId))
                        .perform(ViewActions.replaceText(""))
                    Thread.sleep(500)
                    onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.btLogin)).check(
                        ViewAssertions.matches(
                            CoreMatchers.not(
                                ViewMatchers.isEnabled()
                            )
                        )
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Am I missing something in the mocking of the navController?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved by using the new `TestNavHostController` provided by [androidx navigation test library](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-testing)

Basically, do:

1. Import the dependency in your (app) gradle:

```kotlin
dependencies {
  def nav_version = "2.3.0-alpha06"

  androidTestImplementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-testing:$nav_version"
}
```

2. Mock your nav controller by using `TestNavHostController` in your androidTest:

```kotlin
 // Create a TestNavHostController
val navController = TestNavHostController(
            ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext())

val fragmentArgs = Bundle().apply {
            putParcelable(Constants.RETAIL_CLICK_SOURCE_ID, RetailDetailsClicked.Source.LIST)
            putParcelable(Constants.RETAIL_ID, retail)
        }
        navController.setGraph(R.navigation.retail_details_graph)

        launchFragmentInContainer(
            fragmentArgs, R.style.AppTheme
        ) {
            RetailDetailsFragment().also { fragment ->
                // In addition to returning a new instance of our Fragment,
                // get a callback whenever the fragment’s view is created
                // or destroyed so that we can set the mock NavController
                fragment.viewLifecycleOwnerLiveData.observeForever { viewLifecycleOwner ->
                    if (viewLifecycleOwner != null) {
                        // The fragment’s view has just been created
                        Navigation.setViewNavController(fragment.requireView(), navController)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

That's it!

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been struggling with this problem for days!!

Comment: @TiagoOliveira happy to help :)

Comment: setGraph method is not available in version 2.3.0, why is that?